# Dual boot for the rpi

Tags: raspbian, ssh, vnc, partition, bootloader

Is it possible to have dual boot partitions on usb stick switchable by berryboot loader via vnc.
I need to have a backup boot partition with raspbian Bootable on it.
So that if my primary partition crashes for some reason I can boot to Part2 and reinstall part 1.
This I have to be able to do remotely via ssh or vnc to the berryboot loader to switch the boot partition.
Is there another boot loader out there that has this option?.
The bootloader would be on the 4gb micro sd card and would have an 8gb USB stick with two partitions.
Is this achievable? Or is there a better way too do it?

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer, instead of a comment due to my lack of reputation, but in regards to compiling grub 4 u-boot, it fails to compile. I get an error stating
"Relocations not implemented for A32 ("ARM") instruction set yet" I have attempted this on a 2 and a 1+ with the same result. Is this something that anyone has ran into here?

Answer (score 3):

a simple way is to use Grub for ARM.

UPDATE: It works with a help of U-boot, so the uBoot actually boots up a Grub kernel, take a look [here](https://wiki.linaro.org/LEG/Engineering/Kernel/GRUBonUBOOT) - it's a full step-by-step guide I used when I was working with G4A+uBoot, it is not so hard to compile. To achieve the exact task you want you use `fdisk` to make 2 boot partitions and the rest is for your main system. You're booting the first boot partition, it works, make a sync/copy if the upgrades are made and tested to be working OK. To rollback - just as usual with grub - *just* use another boot menu option.

UPDATE#2: you can use UART TTY to have a console or *just* make a button-press to send a keycodes. It's a simple way of restoring hopelessly-broken system. The more complicated ways are :

- using uBoot you can try to get grub.conf over network like [this way](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Booting_Linux_kernel_using_U-Boot) - it works, I checked
- you can boot an *intermediate* image via Grub or even the uBoot - a third boot partition - with SSH and/or VNC server enabled, wait for connection for some time - and then using `kexec()` system call fire-up the boot variant you need. Or - if the connection is made - you can switch in a script which kernel image will be booted.
- a *rescue* system can be loaded via tftp and executed, so you will have your SSH or VNC environment to fix your boot.

Comment: That is much better

Comment: @SteveRobillard My pleasure! feel free to ask further questions - especially this topic was digged by me deeply, so I can help in troubleshooting

Comment: The question requires that it works over VNC or SSH. Will this?

Comment: So if the uboot fails to boot partition 1 can I ssh to grub and switch to partition 2?

Comment: guys - I've updated my answer

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin I've been trying to use kexec to load a new kernel, and I keep getting "not implemented", even though I am running a kernel I compiled myself with CONFIG_KEXEC enabled.    Can you confirm that kexec works for you?

Comment: @ChristopherBiggs just tested it - it works. On raspberry pi b+ and orangepi pc and banana pi m3 - just checked it

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot). It will give you a boot menu and an easy way to add/remove operating systems. It uses squashfs images for the OS, and an overlay for the changes. This way, both OSes share the same space, but they are still separate. Also, you can reset any of them to their original state easily.

To create a squashfs image of the latest raspbian, you can use my script: https://github.com/geek1011/BerryBootImageCreator

Comment: Can Berryboot be used to make a custom UI for the OS selection menu?