# Booting with Grub on U-Boot

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

I have some specific needs for a bootloader for the Raspberry Pi. I am using a Model 2 B. So the short version is I will have devices scattered throughout the country for various purposes, and these devices need to be high availability.  I also need to be able to access the bootloader remotely. Due to the nature of the product Berryboot doesn't quite fit my needs. Primarily using ssh from remote access instead of VNC, and Berryboot only supports the Berryboot kernel.
According to this thread:
[Dual boot for the rpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/dual-boot-for-the-rpi)
It looks like I should be able to accomplish my goals, if I could only get the thing to boot.

I'm working on configuring Grub for the Raspberry Pi 2 B. Through various steps obtained across different support/forum pages I have been able to successfully U-Boot to boot. The problem arises with the Grub portion. When I attempt to compile Grub for Arm with Uboot as noted here :https://wiki.linaro.org/LEG/Engineering/Kernel/GRUBonUBOOT I receive an error during the make command.

```
{standard input}:31: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r0,cntfrq_el0'
```

When I attempt to just boot with Grub on a system that already has U-Boot, I am able to compile successfully, but U-Boot hangs at

```
Starting Kernel
```

Has anyone else had better luck than I have with this project? Has anyone really tried?
Thanks!